# insert date into wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a date from a PHP page into WordPress field using the below code

```
//calculate new expiration date add 1 year +3 days

$date12 = new DateTime($date9);
$date12->modify('+368 day');
$new_expire= (string)$date12->format('m/d/Y');

$sql_renew = "update wp_usermeta set meta_value=".$new_expire." where user_id=".$user_value." AND meta_key='wpcf-expiration-date'";
$result_renew = $mysqli->query($sql_renew);
```

the output I got is: 0.000247157686604053

I want to insert it into readable format.

Comment: MySQL Date formats are `yyyy-mm-dd` so try `$new_expire = $date12->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: You dont need the cast to `(string)` as the return from a `format()` is a string

Comment: **BIG NOTE** `$sql_renew_message` !== `$sql_renew` Major TYPO

Comment: thank you, I have tried still show 0.000247157686604053.

Comment: yes it is $result_renew, I changed it in my code but forgot to change it here

Comment: your date is a string so need to be wrapped in quotes `meta_value='".$new_expire."' where`

Comment: yes, finally, Many Many Thanks to you RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest using `strtotime` with date manipulations. So maybe try this code and see if it is what you are looking for:

```
$date12 =  strtotime($date9 . '+ 368 days');
$new_expire = date('m/d/Y', $date12);

$sql_renew = "update wp_usermeta set meta_value=".$new_expire." where user_id=".$user_value." AND meta_key='wpcf-expiration-date'";
$result_renew = $mysqli->query($sql_renew_message);
```

Comment: I have tried but still the same output. And even I have tried to add a date as constant value ex, '01-02-2022' after the insert it shows 0.000494559841740850

Comment: Even the timestamp of this date 01-02-2022 is 1643704324, not 0.000494559841740850